# ODBC Microsoft dBase Driver without Office installed

Tags: odbc, dbase

is there some solution how to use 32/64 bit ODBC Microsoft dBase Driver on Windows without Office installed?

Thank you for response.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2148296/62576) to another question has some information that might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jet drivers used to be installed with Windows until the recent Windows editions. You can download ACE drivers for free ( http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 ) Here is an example of usage : [How to read/write dBase III files using C#/.NET ODBC or OLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75705/how-to-read-write-dbase-iii-files-using-c-net-odbc-or-ole/75915#75915)

Comment: However, to install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable, Office has to be installed. Right?

Comment: Why do you think that? You can just install the engine. You can even install a runtime version of MS Access free of charge.

Comment: You right, it can be installed without Office. This solved my problem. Thank you.